# how to prevent hash[] showing up on index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying this code:

```
def index
    if @todos = Todo.all.nil?
        redirect_to todos_path, :notice =>  "No Tasks Yet"
    else
        @todos = Todo.all
    end
end
```

a) It doesn't display the notice when page is blank
b) It displays `[]` mark on `index.html.erb` page when blank

How do I prevent the `[]` showing up on `index.html.erb` when blank? and how to display notice?

Please let me know if further code is needed.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Including a screenshot of the hash mark on index.html.erb page

[image]

**EDIT 2**

This is the `index.html.erb` page so far:

```
<h1>Todo List</h1>

<%= link_to "Create New Todo", new_todo_path %>

<%= @todos.each do |t| %>
    <li><%= t.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 3**

This is the current `application.html.erb` code

```
  <body>

    <% flash.each do |key, value| %> 
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
        <%= value %>
    </div> 
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for `nil` instead of `empty?`. You should use `blank?` instead.
You are also using a single `=` to check for equality of `==`.

Change `@todos = Todo.all.nil?` to `@todos == Todo.all.blank?`

> An object is blank if it's false, empty, or a whitespace string. For
>   example, false, '', ' ', nil, [], and {} are all blank.

Try the following:

```
def index
  if @todos == Todo.all.blank?
    flash[:notice] = 'No Tasks Yet'
    redirect_to todos_path
  else
    @todos = Todo.all
  end
end
```

Comment: you were right in your initial answer ie, `if @todos == Todo.all.blank?` because if I use your current answer, ie, `@todos = Todo.all.blank?` it generates an error ... so intial answer works ... however, the notice doesn't show up on the index page ... am i missing something somewhere? ie, notice on index page?

Comment: also, I've included a screenshot of the hash parenthesis showing up

Comment: in index page if there are no todos

Comment: I did, thank you. Notice still doesn't show up on `index.html.erb` ... am I supposed to put something on the `index.html.erb` to enable the notice to show up?

Comment: Yes. You should have something like this in your application layout. `<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div><%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123480/discussion-between-joel-and-user27307254534534534543675765).